# list inside dictionary wont appear when sent to a put request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

i have a dictionary that should look like this

```
memberlist = [{"id":50,"firstName":"popo"}]
data = {"member": memberlist, "len":1}
```

a put request that looks like

```
url = "http://192.168.100.246:8000/api/group/member/28"
updategroup = requests.put(url,data = data)
```

and this is the view of the url

```
class SetMember(APIView):
    permission_classes=[AllowAny]
    def getObject(self,id):
        try:
            return Group.objects.get(id=id)
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    def get(self,request, id):
            group = self.getObject(id)
            serializer = setMemberSerializer(group)
            return Response(serializer.data)
    def put(self,request,id, format='json'):
        group = self.getObject(id=id)
        serializer = setMemberSerializer(group, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response ({'msg':request.data}, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

well the api doesnt work, so i looked around it to see what was wrong by returning request.data as a response. turns out the data returned from the response looked like this

```
{"msg":{"member":"firstName","len":"1"}}
```

while i was expecting the data to look like this

```
{"msg":[{"id":50,"firstName":"popo"}],"len":"1"}}
```

HOWEVER, when i changed the data sent into something like (i added single quotes to the list and didnt use a variable anymore)

```
data = {"member": '[{"id":50,"firstName":"popo"}]', "len":1}
```

everything works fine!

any help or tips appreciated would be nice

Comment: What does `print(request.parsers, request.content_type)` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with DRF is best to send data as JSON:

```
updategroup = requests.put(url, json=data)
```

This way, the data will be converted to JSON string and the contentType will be set to 'application/json'. Based on the contentType header DRF will use the appropriate parser for your data.

Comment: damn so that was the issue, do you perhaps have any links that can give more information about drf and django requests?

Comment: The official docs for DRF requests: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/ , and DRF parsers: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/ provide a solid base for dealing with this kind of problems.